# How do I Style ListView Items?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` that is data bound and I want to alter the font properties for each item. I'm not having much luck finding the appropriate properties. The `ListView` is pretty simple so I don't expect it to be too difficult to change, I'm just not finding what I'm wanting as of yet.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Updates}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeStamp}" Header="TimeStamp" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UpdateData}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Are each item going to have the same font property changes with the same values or different font properties for each item or a subset of items?

Comment: @Aaron, I would like the string values in each item to be the same but not the same as the column headers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can set the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Updates}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeStamp}" Header="TimeStamp" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UpdateData}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Note that it will apply to the *items* of the `ListView`, not the `ListView` itself (e.g. the column headers won't be affected). If you want to apply those properties to the whole `ListView`, you can set them directly on the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Updates}"
          Foreground="Blue" FontSize="14" ...>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I wanted to apply a style to the item strings but not affect ListView headers, etc. Thanks!