# WPF: How do I programmatically style my ListView so that all rows have a certain background color and height?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, styles, styling

I can't seem to wrap my head around something. Say I have the following logic in my code:

```
namespace WPFTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        ObservableCollection<Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            ListView listView = new ListView();
            GridView gridView = new GridView();
            listView.View = gridView;
            GridViewColumn timeStampColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            timeStampColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");
            GridViewColumnHeader timeStampHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            timeStampHeader.Content = "Time";
            timeStampColumn.Header = timeStampHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(timeStampColumn);
            GridViewColumn messageColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            messageColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Text");
            GridViewColumnHeader messageHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            messageHeader.Content = "Message";
            messageColumn.Header = messageHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(messageColumn);
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = messages;
            listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
        }

        public class Message
        {

            public Message(DateTime aDate, String aText)
            {
                Date = aDate;
                Text = aText;
            }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public String Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I programmatically style my ListView so that all rows have a certain background color and height? Note, I want to avoid doing a foreach loop on the ListView's Items list and setting each ListViewItem's properties, because this list may have very many items and this could be expensive. Instead, is there not some way to do this programmatically using the Style class, or perhaps some run-time logic?

Comment: why would you want to do such stuff in code-behind and not via xaml `Template`'s? What's the compulsion factor here to use code-behind?

Comment: @Viv - Well, then how would this look in the XAML for the above example? I don't have a ListView in XAML, its dynamically generated, so I need the XAML styling to work for a dynamically generated ListView, if at all possible.

Comment: firstly why don't you have the `ListView` in xaml? The content for the `ListView` can come through `ItemsSource` bindings making it dynamic, but are you at a use case where you wouldn't know if you even need a `ListView` in the Window? even in such cases I'd have xaml either show or hide control's accordingly. I can't think of a reason why this "has" to be from code-behind. As for your question even if you have to generate the ListView in code-behind, yes you can get a `Style` or any resource defined in xaml by using things like `TryFindResource(...)`, however pls consider not going for it.

Comment: @Viv - I made this example code the simplest case of a much larger project for people to better understand the problem and help me find solutions. I am using Telerik's RadPanes in my project, so I have to dynamically add these controls to each pane, and I can't simply mark everything up. Now, is there a way to programmatically define a Style for the ListView for its Items collection? Could you post an example of how you would use TryFindResource here?

Comment: Man, if you gonna programm in WPF you better get used to XAML. Then styling gets easy, there are many tutorials. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474436/how-do-i-style-listview-items) for example. You can create `UserControl` that has all this controls that you add in code, and some styles too.

Comment: At this point, the fact that everyone is leaning towards a XAML solution makes me want to see a C# solution even more. As much as I understand that XAML is pretty and easy to use, a XAML solution goes beyond the scope of my question, which is strictly a programmatic solution that I seek. Now, is there a way of changing a global stylesheets in XAML for all ListViewItems in an application in WPF? I wouldn't mind seeing how that's done in XAML. I'm going to play devil's advocate. Now I REALLY want to see how you would do this in the code-behind.

Comment: `At this point, the fact that everyone is leaning towards a XAML solution makes me want to see a C# solution even more.` - Yeh that's a great motivator for me to spend time and post some code :P Just use MSDN or google for a `TryFindResource()` example. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.tryfindresource.aspx) and base your usage based on the scope of where you define your resource. Now I'm REALLY going to ignore this thread from now.

Comment: @Viv - I hate it when people try to re-scope my questions; there is value to answers on these subjects for me and/or other people who visit here. You want more motivation? Down-voting my question out of spite makes me want to see a C# solution even more ;)

Comment: @Alexandru Look I really ain't got anything against you for your approach. I'm not forcing a xaml approach either but there is normally value in people's opinion. hell that's why this question is on a community forum. If you wanna ignore it that's upto you. Also I ain't holding info from you. I said `TryFindResource(...)` abt 58mins ago in my comment. Then added the MSDN link as well. If you had trouble with that I din't see you add anything abt it than just want code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. You can do it this way as an example:

```
Style style = new Style();
style.TargetType = typeof(ListViewItem);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Pink));
listView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

Edit: You can also conditionally set a style on the ListView's Items using a trigger for certain values from your data set. I found this very useful, so this may help others as well:

```
DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger();
trigger.Binding = new Binding("Text");
trigger.Value = "This is a test.";
trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Pink));
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
listView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

The above code will only set the background of the row under the condition that the Text field is set to "This is a test."

Answer (score 2):

GridView columns don't support styling, only header styling. Instead use a cell template to style column cells. This allows you to have different styles for different columns. For example you want currency columns to be right aligned but text columns to be left aligned.

This is how it looks using XAML for your Time column with red background style.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Time">                            
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

This can be done in code. [FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx) class is a deprecated class which supports the creation of templates. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx) method of the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class. Below code should be modified to allow for different styles depending on type of column.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));

    ListView listView = new ListView();
    GridView gridView = new GridView();
    listView.View = gridView;

    gridView.Columns.Add(CreateGridViewColumn("Time", "Date"));
    gridView.Columns.Add(CreateGridViewColumn("Message","Text"));

    listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = messages });

    MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
}

private static GridViewColumn CreateGridViewColumn(string header, string bindingPath)
{
    GridViewColumn gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();
    gridViewColumn.Header = new GridViewColumnHeader() { Content = header };

    string xaml = @"
        <DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""> 
            <TextBlock Text=""{Binding " + bindingPath + @"}""> 
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType=""{x:Type TextBlock}"">
                        <Setter Property=""Background"" Value=""Red"" />
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>";
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    gridViewColumn.CellTemplate = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;

    return gridViewColumn;
}
```

Comment: +1 because it is interesting, although I just wanted to style rows, not columns. I figured it out though, check out my answer :P Thanks for that!