# How do I style the text wrapping on ListViewItems in a ListView if I've fixed the HeightProperty of all ListViewItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styling, listviewitem

Here is my code (you can create a new WPF project in VS and run it, just set the Grid's name in the MainWindow's XAML to be MainGrid):

```
namespace WPFTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        ObservableCollection<Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message.")); 
            ListView listView = new ListView();
            Style style = new Style();
            style.TargetType = typeof(ListViewItem);
            DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger();
            trigger.Binding = new Binding("Text");
            trigger.Value = "This is a test.";
            trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Pink));
            style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.HeightProperty, 20.0));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0)));
            listView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
            GridView gridView = new GridView();
            listView.View = gridView;
            GridViewColumn timeStampColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            timeStampColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");
            GridViewColumnHeader timeStampHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            timeStampHeader.Content = "Time";
            timeStampColumn.Header = timeStampHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(timeStampColumn);
            GridViewColumn messageColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            messageColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Text");
            GridViewColumnHeader messageHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            messageHeader.Content = "Message";
            messageColumn.Header = messageHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(messageColumn);
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = messages;
            listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
        }

        public class Message
        {

            public Message(DateTime aDate, String aText)
            {
                Date = aDate;
                Text = aText;
            }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public String Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, multi-line messages show up kind of nasty in the ListView since I've constrained the Height of each ListViewItem to be 20.0. I really just want the first line of the message of text to show up. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Alexandru is there a reason you chose to create all of these things in code-behind?  Ideally you would have your ListView defined in XAML and set it's ItemsSource, etc... while having your "Messages" defined in some separate viewModel class.

This would alleviate a lot of the complexity and would allow you to customize the look of each ListViewItem by defining an ItemTemplate.

I will implement what I'm explaining for you and post.

Comment: @user1631520 - Yes, please check out my other question here; I go through the reasoning in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594349/wpf-how-do-i-programmatically-style-my-listview-so-that-all-rows-have-a-certain/17596097#17596097

Comment: Ok well I posted an answer that fixes your problem (albeit I did not add your header columns)...

You could probably just translate that to code-behind

Comment: Also I don't feel like commenting on that other post so I will comment here.

You could keep the ListView in code behind and separate that DataTemplate I have below into a ResourceDictionary.  Then all you have to do is assign the ItemTemplate to the ListView in code behind by finding that resource.

Good luck.  Hopefully I've answered your question well enough.

Comment: @user1631520 - Yes, this is an awesome solution. Thank you very much. I was thinking of doing exactly that but programmatically! :D

Comment: @user1631520 - I can see why this works, because you set a horizontal StackPanel to constrain the rows. I wonder if its expensive to set a StackPanel for each row if you have a lot of rows at once. Something I gotta test out.

Comment: @user1631520 - Combining the two solutions I've seen today, I suppose you can do what I have below, check out my answer (just about to post it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to your problem.  SORRY FOR FORMATTING...I STILL CAN'T GET SOverFlow's formatting to work propertly for me.

1. I have done is removed all of the creation code from the code-behind file for your XAML.  I moved the definition of the Messages to it's own ViewModel class (MSGviewModel.cs)
2. In the XAML for your main window, I've defined the ListView and set up a simple ItemTemplate.  This ItemTemplate will display the date and the Message Text.  The TextBLock to display the message text is limited to a max height of 20.
3. I defined a tooltip for that TextBlock.  That tooltip is bound to the full Text property of the Message.  This way you can mouseOver the single line Message and have the full text displayed.

MAINWINDOW XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FixListView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>        
            <DataTemplate>          
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" MaxHeight="20">
                  <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                  </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text=" -- "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
      </Grid>
    </Window>
```

MAINWINDOW - Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.DataContext = new MSGviewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

VIEWMODEL Class:

```
public class MSGviewModel
{
private ObservableCollection<Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages
{
  get { return messages; }
}


public MSGviewModel()
{
  messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
  messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
  messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
  messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message.")); 
}
}

public class Message
{

  public Message(DateTime aDate, String aText)
  {
    Date = aDate;
    Text = aText;
  }

  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public String Text { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it while maintaining the current code:

```
namespace WPFTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        ObservableCollection<Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message.")); 
            ListView listView = new ListView();
            Style style = new Style();
            style.TargetType = typeof(ListViewItem);
            DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger();
            trigger.Binding = new Binding("Text");
            trigger.Value = "This is a test.";
            trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Pink));
            style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.HeightProperty, 20.0));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0)));
            listView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
            GridView gridView = new GridView();
            listView.View = gridView;
            GridViewColumn timeStampColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            timeStampColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");
            GridViewColumnHeader timeStampHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            timeStampHeader.Content = "Time";
            timeStampColumn.Header = timeStampHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(timeStampColumn);
            GridViewColumn messageColumn = CreateGridViewColumn("Message", "Text");
            gridView.Columns.Add(messageColumn);
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = messages;
            listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
        }

        private static GridViewColumn CreateGridViewColumn(string header, string bindingPath)
        {
            GridViewColumn gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            gridViewColumn.Header = new GridViewColumnHeader() { Content = header };
            string xaml = @"
            <DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""> 
              <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"">
                <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Text}"" MaxHeight=""20"">
                  <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Text}""/>
                  </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="" -- ""/>
                <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Date}""/>
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>";
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            gridViewColumn.CellTemplate = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;

            return gridViewColumn;
        }

        public class Message
        {

            public Message(DateTime aDate, String aText)
            {
                Date = aDate;
                Text = aText;
            }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public String Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```