# Horizontal line after list view item in grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I insert a horizontal line after each list view item in a grid?

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="Users">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="300">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Height="32" Text="{Binding Name}" />                           
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Height="32" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I tried defining Border after DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue">
```

but that only added a border around each of the data template items. How do I insert a horizontal separator after each row?

Comment: Try giving the Border a `BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"`

Comment: Thanks, how do I make it a single line that extends to the 2nd "Age" column?

Comment: Derp, good point. Try ItemContainerStyle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4474474/424129

Comment: Wow that worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ought to be able to set a row style via the `ItemContainerStyle`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474474/424129

You'd want to set a `BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"` to have only a bottom border.